# Call again a function when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have the following function:

```
  const getCurrentCharacters = () => {
    let result;
    let characters; 

    if(selectedMovie !== 'default'){
      characters = state.data.filter(movie => movie.title === selectedMovie)[0].characterConnection.characters;
      result = characters; 
    }else if(selectedSpecies !== 'default'){
      const currentSpecies = characters.filter(char => char.species.name === selectedSpecies || char.species === selectedSpecies);
      result = currentSpecies; 
    }else if (selectedPlanets !== 'default'){
      const currentPlanets = characters.filter(char => char.homeworld.name === selectedPlanets); 
      result = currentPlanets; 
    }else{
      return []; 
    }   

    return result; 
  }
```

It makes use of the `useState` hooks:

```
  const [selectedSpecies, setSelectedSpecies] = useState("default");
  const [selectedPlanets, setSelectedPlanets] = useState("default");
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState("default");
```

I would like to function to recall itself whenever any of these is updated. Can you provide a basic example on how you would do this. The context is not important as long as i can figure out how to call the function whenever a change occurs, i can figure out the rest  myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that case if you want to trigger any function on a specific state change there is a hook called `useEffect`. You can run side effects with that setup. Read from the documentation:

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components.

Let me give you an example:

```
const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState('default');

// ... other states, code part

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('selectedMovie has been changed');

   // ... here you can implement your logic for state changes
   // ... like that function call
}, [selectedMovie]);
```

Suggested read: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

I hope that helps!

Comment: @Kevin.a It has to be placed still inside your function component. If you ask me I would put between the `useState` parts and the `return` statement in the component. I hope that helps!